# ScaffoldMessenger does not hide snackbar on navigator pop

Tags: flutter

When I was using the old api for showing the snackbar, the snackbar used to disappear when the user goes back to the previous page.

With the new `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()`, the snackbar stays visible.

Also, when I add a snackbar action for removing the snackbar, pressing on the `hide` action, does not hide the snackbar after going back to the previous page.

How can I remove the snackbar after the user leaves the current page?

```
void _successSnackbar(BuildContext context, String message) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkCircle, color: Colors.green[400], size: 35),
          const SizedBox(width: 15),
          Flexible(child: Text(message, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[400], fontSize: 14.5))),
        ],
      ),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Hide',
        onPressed: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        },
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: removes the current SnackBar https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/removeCurrentSnackBar.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
**Reason** 
from official document https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger
The `ScaffoldMessenger` creates a scope in which all descendant Scaffolds register to receive `SnackBars`, **which is how they persist across these transitions**
so In your case, root `ScaffoldMessenger` provided by the `MaterialApp` let all descendant `Scaffolds` receive `SnackBars`

**Solution**
unless a new `ScaffoldMessenger` scope is created further down the tree. By instantiating your own `ScaffoldMessenger`, you can control which Scaffolds receive `SnackBars` 
To auto hide `SnackBar` when pop from second page, you can in second page wrap `Scaffold` with  `ScaffoldMessenger` and in my example also need `Builder`

code snippet in `Page2`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      child: Scaffold(
         ...
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Second route"),
                Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _successSnackbar(context, "messge of page 2");
                      },
                      child: Text('show message'));
                }),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Page 1',
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Go to page 2'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  void _successSnackbar(BuildContext context, String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green[400], size: 35),
            const SizedBox(width: 15),
            Flexible(
                child: Text(message,
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.green[400], fontSize: 14.5))),
          ],
        ),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Hide',
          onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
          },
        ),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 20),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("page 2"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Second route"),
                Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _successSnackbar(context, "messge of page 2");
                      },
                      child: Text('show message'));
                }),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(
                        context,
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('Pop'))
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked perfectly. The code was thorough and clear. Thank you so much for your time brother.

Comment: This is the first clear and working example of local ScaffoldMessenger I have seen. Great help!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that we pass the wrong `context` to `ScaffoldMessenger.of()` method. We need `context` of a child of `Scaffold`.

You can wrap your widget in `Builder` to get the right `context`.

In my case it was not possible, so another solution is to use a `GlobalKey`.
In your widget `State` class add this line:
`final _scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();`, use `_scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar()` to show snackbar, and wrap your `Scaffold` with `ScaffoldMessenger`:

```
ScaffoldMessenger(
  key: _scaffoldMessengerKey,
  child: Scaffold(...)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the context and look for the ScaffoldMessenger pass directly the scaffoldMessenger:

```
void _successSnackbar(ScaffoldMessengerState scaffoldMessengerState , String message) {
  scaffoldMessengerState.hideCurrentSnackBar();

  scaffoldMessengerState.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkCircle, color: Colors.green[400], size: 35),
          const SizedBox(width: 15),
          Flexible(child: Text(message, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[400], fontSize: 14.5))),
        ],
      ),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Hide',
        onPressed: () {
          scaffoldMessengerState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
        },
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    ),
  );
```

To close the snackBar automatically when the page is poped you will have to put a scaffoldMessengerState.hideCurrentSnackBar(); on a will pop callback or in a naavigator observer